# VBA Module naming conventions

Tags: vba, excel, naming-conventions

A quick question about Naming of VBA modules. I've posted this in a few related  posts but they are old and evidently unobserved at this point and have gotten no responses. So I ask it here. When naming a module in VBA it defaults to the name "Module#".  I usually just add my name to it such that it becomes "Module_MyCodeName".  Is it ok to remove the "Module#" name altogether and make it just "MyCodeName"? I've seen many naming things but nothing that actually says "Why yes! You CAN remove "Module" and it will not affect the functionality." I know it's a basic basic basic question but I really don't know. Maybe just a brain fart or something.///

Comment: Yes you can, I always rename the Module to something more meaningful... but why not just try it first?

Comment: You can call it *whatever* you like so long as its a valid identifier (i.e. no spaces) the name is not a reserved word or in conflict with something else.  
I would say (subjectively) the most commonly seen VBA convention is `modSomeName` and `clsSomeName` for classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the [Lezynski prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leszynski_naming_convention) *m-*. Unless you are developing VBA in a team (which you shouldn't) it shouldn't matter though.
I can only imagine how and why you would use *mFormating* and *mGlobalVariables* (by the way do consider the [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) convention when naming your elements).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why one shouldn't be developing VBA in a team? What if you're using a VBE add-in that gives you IDE-integrated source control?

Comment: For the love of god..... stop it with the hungarian notation. [Nobody does it right](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

Comment: I firmly believe that VBA has its limitations. Larger projects in my opinion should not use MS Excel as native environment but as an export format if need be. It's not good at handling multi-user, not good at authenticating either, cannot handle database functions well, has an upper limit on RAM and re-runs everything all the time rendering it useless for some pretty basic uses even on small (~10,000-500,000 record) datasets.